# Is there a way to make a layer behave differently during forward pass for model.fit() and model.evaluate() in a customised Keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to reproduce the incomplete convolution layer with a linear profile (gamma) proposed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.07830.pdf), where a operation called incomplete dot product (IDP) is introduced, which decides the percentage of the input channels to be used for inference. I customised the incomplete convolutional layer as below:

```
class IncompleteConv2D(layers.Conv2D):
  def __init__(self, IDP=1, **kwargs):
    self.IDP = IDP
    super(IncompleteConv2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def call(self, inputs, training=None):
    def linear_profile(N, training):
      g_list = []
      num_channels_in_used = []
      if training != False:
        for i in range(1, N+1):
          g_list.append(1 - i/N)
        g = tf.stack([g_list])
        return g, num_channels_in_used
      num_channels_in_used = np.floor(N*self.IDP).astype(np.int32)
      if num_channels_in_used == 0:
        for i in range(1, N+1):
          g_list.append(1 - i/N)
      else:
        for i in range(1, num_channels_in_used+1):
          g_list.append(1 - i/N)
      g = tf.stack([g_list])
      return g, num_channels_in_used

    num_channels_in = inputs.shape[-1]
    num_channels_out = self.kernel.shape[-1]
    
    gamma, num_channels_in_used = linear_profile(num_channels_in, training)
    
    g_converted_list = []
    if training != False:
      for j in range(num_channels_out):
        g_converted = tf.reshape(
          tf.broadcast_to(gamma, [self.kernel[:,:,:,j].shape[0]*self.kernel[:,:,:,j].shape[1], self.kernel[:,:,:,j].shape[2]]), 
          tf.shape(self.kernel[:,:,:,j])
        )
        
        g_converted = tf.expand_dims(g_converted, 3)
        g_converted_list.append(g_converted)

    else:
      for j in range(num_channels_out):
        if (num_channels_in_used == 0):
          g_converted = tf.reshape(
            tf.broadcast_to(gamma, [self.kernel[:,:,:,j].shape[0]*self.kernel[:,:,:,j].shape[1], self.kernel[:,:,:,j].shape[2]]), 
            tf.shape(self.kernel[:,:,:,j])
          )
        else:
          g_converted = tf.reshape(
            tf.broadcast_to(gamma, [self.kernel[:,:,:,j].shape[0]*self.kernel[:,:,:,j].shape[1], num_channels_in_used]), 
            [self.kernel[:,:,:,j].shape[0], self.kernel[:,:,:,j].shape[1], num_channels_in_used]
          )
        g_converted = tf.expand_dims(g_converted, 3)
        g_converted_list.append(g_converted)

      
      if (num_channels_in_used > 0):
        self.kernel = self.kernel[:,:,:num_channels_in_used,:]
        inputs = inputs[:,:,:,:num_channels_in_used]
    
    gamma_converted = tf.concat(g_converted_list, 3)
    mean, var = tf.nn.moments(gamma_converted * self.kernel, axes=[0, 1, 2], keepdims=True)
    result = self.convolution_op(
      inputs, (gamma_converted * self.kernel - mean) / tf.sqrt(var + 1e-10)
    )
    if self.use_bias:
      result = result + self.bias
    return result
```

Basically, a linear profile gamma is learned during training, and IDP between 0 and 1 should be set during inference. In other words, IDP should remain 1 at all times during training. With this `IncompleteConv2D` layer defined, an example model initialisation is as below:

```
x = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
output = IncompleteConv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", IDP=1)(x)
output = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(output)
output = IncompleteConv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", IDP=1)(output)
output = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(output)
output = layers.Flatten()(output)
output = layers.Dropout(0.5)(output)
output = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(output)

model = Model(x, output)

model.summary()
```

where IDP=1 is set as a parameter for the layer (which I believe is not the best way, since IDP is only related to the inference phase...) **Note that IDP has to be set as 1 here because for the testing part of the training phase all channels should be utilised.**

After compilation, the code for training phase is as below:

```
model_history = model.fit(training_generator,
                          validation_data=validation_generator,
                          verbose=1,
                          epochs=1)
```

where the validation accuracy during training phase is evaluated with training=False within the call method for the IncompleteConv2D layer, with IDP=1.

Now comes the tricky part, for evaluation:

```
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test_data, y_test, IDP=0.8, verbose=1)
```

An IDP argument between 0 and 1 should be fed into the evaluation phase. However, IDP is not recognised.

TypeError: Invalid keyword arguments: ['IDP']

**Problem:** I looked into customising the model.evaluate() [here](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/) using test_step method of a CustomModel, but it seemed that you cannot add your own argument for model.evaluate().

If this can be solved, I expect that during model.evaluate(IDP=0.8), this new IDP will be passed in the call method during forward pass for inference, thus overriding the original IDP (which was set to 1).

Is there any way I can achieve this? Any help is highly appreciated.

---

**Updated:** Following the useful pointers from @Innat, I inherited the keras.Model class with IDP initialised as follow:

```
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, IDP=1, **kwargs):
    super(CustomModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.IDP = tf.Variable(IDP, dtype=tf.float32)

model = CustomModel(inputs=x, outputs=output, IDP=1)
```

With the help of a custom callback, I managed to change the IDP attribute in the CustomModel class to 0.8 at the beginning of `model.evaluate()`.

```
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_test_begin(self, logs=None):
    # self.model.IDP.assign(0.8)
    for layer in self.model.layers:
      if isinstance(layer, IncompleteConv2D):
        layer.IDP = 0.8

test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test_data, y_test, verbose=1, callbacks=[CustomCallback()])
```

However, from the observation that the test accuracy is similar to the validation accuracy, I believe the IDP attribute in the `IncompleteConv2D` layer class remained 1 for `model.evaluate()`.

What should I do next to link IDP in CustomModel to IDP in `IncompleteConv2D`, as in, how to pass a model attribute to its layer?

Comment: Pointer: (a). inherit the model class (b). initialize target variable (IDP) (c). use callback to control it.

Comment: @Innat Thanks! Please take a look at my updated question.

Comment: Good progress. You need to create `tf.Variable` in the model class for IDP, i.e. `self.IDP = tf.Variable(IDP, ...)` and in the callaback use `.assign` attribute to update its value.

Comment: @Innat Thanks again. `self.IDP` in the model class gets updated, but `self.IDP` in the IncompleteConv2D class doesn't.

Comment: IDP is defined in IncompleteCN layer. So, in callback,  iterate over the model layer and get ithe target layer instance (ICN) and update IDP.

Comment: @Innat Please have a look at the updated CustomCallback. I also quit inheriting the model class since IDP can just be defined in IncompleteConv2D layer I assume. This time I really expected it to work but again it didn't. The layer's IDP attribute did change to 0.8 (I printed it out) but it was not used in model.evaluate() somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, you've created a custom layer (`IncompleteConv2D`) and initialize a variable of a scaler value which further is used in `call` method. Now, you want to change this value in testing time or inference time. In `keras`, one way to achieve this by using the callback API. Here I'm showing a general solutions, and not using your `IncompleteConv2D` layer.

---

Let's import some necessary libraries and define a simple custom layer. Here in the `call` method, we will print out the predefined scaler value.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import keras.layers as layers
import numpy as np

class StandardizedConv2DWithCall(layers.Conv2D):
    def __init__(self, some_var, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.some_var = tf.Variable(
            some_var, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False
            )

    def call(self, inputs):
        print('printing from call fn: ', self.some_var)

        mean, var = tf.nn.moments(
            self.kernel, axes=[0, 1, 2], keepdims=True
        )
        result = self.convolution_op(
            inputs, (self.kernel - mean) / tf.sqrt(var + 1e-10)
        )
        if self.use_bias:
            result = result + self.bias
        return result
```

Prepare some data to train and test.

```
# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

def prepare_ds(x, y, take=None):
    if take:
        x, y = x[:take], y[:take]
    x = tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.float32), axis=3)
    x = tf.repeat(x, repeats=3, axis=3)
    x = tf.divide(x, 255.) 
    x = tf.image.resize(x, [28, 28])
    y = tf.one_hot(y, depth=10)
    return x, y

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train, y_train = prepare_ds(x_train, y_train, take=100)
x_test, y_test = prepare_ds(x_test, y_test, take=50)
x_train.shape, y_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_test.shape
(TensorShape([100, 28, 28, 3]),
 TensorShape([100, 10]),
 TensorShape([50, 28, 28, 3]),
 TensorShape([50, 10]))
```

Let's define a dummy model, which contains the above custom layer.

```
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28,28,3)),
        StandardizedConv2DWithCall(
            some_var= 1., filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"
            ),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        StandardizedConv2DWithCall(
            some_var=1., filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"
            ),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)
model.summary()
```

Run the model with eager model to see the print value of the above custom layer.

```
batch_size = 128
model.compile(
    loss="categorical_crossentropy", 
    optimizer="adam", 
    metrics=["accuracy"],
    run_eagerly=True
)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1)

printing from call fn:  <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>
printing from call fn:  <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 179ms/step - loss: 40.5805 - accuracy: 0.0400
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f653355bd00>
```

Printed value `1.0` as set. Now, let's define a custom callback, which will be used to change this value in testing time.

```
class UpdateSomeVariableCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, update_value):
        super().__init__()
        self.update_value = update_value
        
    def on_test_begin(self, logs=None):
      for layer in self.model.layers:
          if isinstance(layer, StandardizedConv2DWithCall):
              layer.some_var.assign(self.update_value)
```

Run the test

```
# test 1 
loss, acc = model.evaluate(
    x_test, 
    y_test, 
    callbacks=[
        UpdateSomeVariableCallback(update_value=0.8)
    ]
)
printing from call fn:  <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=0.8>
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 26.0635 - accuracy: 0.3600

# test 2 
loss, acc = model.evaluate(
    x_test, 
    y_test, 
    callbacks=[
        UpdateSomeVariableCallback(update_value=0.2)
    ]
)
printing from call fn:  <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=0.2>
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 26.0635 - accuracy: 0.3600
```

As we can see that, the variable is updated and printed accordingly in the call method.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I managed to get it work by ensuring the following two simultaneously a) IDP was set as `tf.Variable` b) `run_eagerly=True` for model.compile(). I have some numpy stuff for the use of for loops in the IncompleteConv2D layer so only eagerly can prevent the error for IDP tensor. Next I will dig into removing numpy so graph mode can be enabled for better training speed.

Comment: You can try replacing numpy to corresponding tensorflow operations, or you can try [tf.experimental.numpy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/numpy) API. However, if the main issue (getting updated value in call) is solved, please accept the answer so other may know. For ICN layer implementaiton, if you face any issue, please post new questions for that. Hope this helps.